# MySQL returns some rows 3 times AGAIN

Tags: php, mysql

Still returns the same results! Got rid of divs. Now the query is:

```
SELECT w.windate,
       w.wintime,
       w.field,
       w.htname,
       w.vtname,
       w.plateumpire,
       w.fieldumpire1,
       w.fieldumpire2,
       w.fieldumpire3,
       p.pteamname,
       p.teamcoach
FROM playerteams AS p 
  INNER JOIN sportsdb_wins AS w ON p.pteamname IN (w.htname,w.vtname)
WHERE p.teamcoach = '$coachid'
AND   p.forteam = '$teamid'
```

but no joy!

I am trying to display a list of teams that all have the same p.teamcoach. The playerteams table contains each team and has teamcoach set to that coach. sportsdb_wins contains a list of scheduled games that I want to display for a given coach.

Comment: This should go in your other question, as it would be useful to have all this one place. Second of all, check your database, do you have duplicate data??? I ask before even looking at your code.

Comment: It's a typical behaviour with join queries in one-to-many and many-to-many relationships. Have you tried a `GROUP BY` clause?

Comment: run the query in phpmyadmin with various values...does it return expected results? also post your PHP as well as how you are setting `$coachid` and `$teamid`

Comment: It seems like you're missing a relationship, like netcoder pointed out, between playerteams and sportsdb_wins

Comment: In answer to Ross & sauceMaster - I ran the query in phpmyadmin with exactly the same results! And no there are no duplicate entries.

Comment: For the PHP: I am not a coach so I am just using $coachid = '4d25087435153'; (which I know is the id of a coach). As for $teamid=$_SESSION['teamid']; (a number like 11 indicating which team the user is registered in).

Comment: Marc B- yes I did and it returned just one record, so lovely.

Comment: True North - yes I see what you mean. I am great coder but a beginner at SQL... There is a relationship in the JOIN clause - htname (hometeamname) and vtname in w are compared to p.pteamname...

Comment: @Carl: Ok, so if only one teamid/coachid has this problem, then the query is fine and you've got some data data somewhere, tied in to that coach/team id combo.

Answer (score 0):

How are you associating team coaches to teams. I would suggest you have a table for coaches and foreign key this to the playerteams table. That way your coaches are only entered once. Something like...

```
SELECT w.windate,
w.wintime,
w.field,
w.htname,
w.vtname,
w.plateumpire,
p.pteamname,
pc.coach_name
FROM player_coaches AS pc
INNER JOIN playerteams AS p
ON p.coachId = pc.coachId
INNER JOIN sportsdb_wins AS w
ON p.pteamname IN (w.htname, w.vtname)
WHERE p.coachId = '$coachId'
AND p.forteam = '$teamId'
```

Comment: So a coaches table containing coachid of all umpires (I think there are 5) would comprise a table with 5 entries, FOREIGN keyed to p.teamcoach (with lots of entries) would be ok? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks everyone for trying to help.